# Don't let long text in child extent parent vertically

Tags: css, reactjs

I create a React App (with MUI) which contains a list of descriptions (red box = title, blue box = description). My goal is that each item has the same height and that the text inside the blue box only uses the remaining height (like in the bottom item) of the parent without expanding it (see blue box of top item).

I tried using something like

```
.line-clamp {
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    overflow: hidden;
 }
```

But I want to use a more dynamic approach and not always see only 3 lines. For instance, if the window is resized more or less text should be shown depending on the space. Is that possible without specifying a fixed height for the parent?

The title and description are properties passed from the list manager and inserted in jsx with the usual syntax

```
<div class="???">
    <div class="flex ...">
        <h2>{props.title}</h2>
        <IconButton />
    </div> 
    <div class="???">
        {props.description}
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I see the only solution in the calculated number of lines using javascript.
You could do something like this :

```js
setLineClamp()

window.onresize = setLineClamp;

function setLineClamp() {
  document.querySelectorAll('.card-content').forEach(el => {
    el.style.bottom = 0;
    const height = el.offsetHeight;
    const lineHeight = parseInt( getComputedStyle(el).getPropertyValue('line-height'), 10 );
    const lines = Math.round( height / lineHeight );
    el.style.webkitLineClamp = lines;
    el.style.bottom = 'auto';
  })
}
```

```css
.card {
  max-width: 600px;
  display: flex;
}

.card-image {
  height: 180px;
  width: 180px;
  background-color: gray;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex: none;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.card-main {
  flex: auto;
  min-width: 1px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.card-title {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.card-body {
  flex: auto;
  min-height: 40px;
  position: relative;
}

.card-content {
  line-height: 1.4; /* must be set */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-image">Image</div>
  <div class="card-main">
    <div class="card-title">Title</div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <div class="card-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic, repudiandae, animi, accusamus quod consequatur eum deleniti magni ad enim numquam temporibus deserunt nam ullam natus alias quibusdam maiores voluptates nihil molestias cumque provident. Doloribus, tempora ducimus dolorem distinctio odit quam omnis nulla fuga praesentium eos laboriosam eius quod recusandae quis alias velit quisquam maiores atque cumque neque unde ratione obcaecati est aut modi nostrum nisi a quas quo voluptatibus aperiam animi sint deserunt quasi qui numquam quae laudantium consequatur voluptatum incidunt. Vitae quod qui odio eligendi est architecto numquam exercitationem id distinctio illo. Eaque, beatae repudiandae vel impedit laborum blanditiis.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion :) I will try it. Nevertheless, maybe I can find a css based approach.